# `sed` works, but `sed -i` returns an error

Tags: linux, sed

This line works:

```
sed -r -e 's/^([^#a-z]+)localhost/\1hostname.domain hostname localhost/' /etc/hosts
```

But adding the itty option "i":

```
sed -ir -e 's/^([^#a-z]+)localhost/\1hostname.domain hostname localhost/' /etc/hosts
```

Results in:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

Can someone tell me what's going on??

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Sed command - order of option flags matters? (-ir vs -ri)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525378/sed-command-order-of-option-flags-matters-ir-vs-ri)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've turned off the `-r` (extended syntax) option, because what you append to `-i` isn't more options, but an optional backup suffix. From the manpage:

> ```
> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>
>    edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
> ```

So just separate them:

```
sed -i -r -e 's/^([^#a-z]+)localhost/\1hostname.domain hostname localhost/' /etc/hosts
```

Comment: Yup, I'm dumb. Saw the entry for `-i` in `man sed` just mere seconds before you posted your answer. Marking yours as correct. (And no, I don't need any backup, so your `-ir` is not needed; just `-i -r`)

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the answer. SO isn't about telling people to RTFM, but about telling them where in the FM they should look, and why, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should separate options: write `-i -r` and not `-ir`, since `-i` may interpret `r` as the suffix to append to the old unedited file, so that `-r` is not taken

Answer (score 1):

"-ir" means something different from "-i -r" or "-ri", see the man page.