# sed (or awk) regular expression to replace substring of match

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I have a text file ("file.txt") with the following contents:

```
#   disutil_screening = 0.00000; # favorable
    disutil_screening = 0.00009; # base
#   disutil_screening = 0.00019; # unfavorable
```

I need to toggle which of these 3 lines (either the "favorable", "base", or "unfavorable") is commented-out using GNU Sed.

I know that I can match the "favorable" line with code such as the following (where, as a dummy example, I simply replace text with "aaa"):

```
$ cat file.txt | sed -r 's/#[\t]disutil_screening[\ =0-9\.;]+# favorable/aaa/'
aaa
    disutil_screening = 0.00009; # base
#   disutil_screening = 0.00019; # unfavorable
```

However, this example Sed statement is obviously far from what I actually want.  I need a Sed expression that will merely remove the leading "#".   That is, I need a Sed expression (`$EXPR`) such that the contents of "file.txt" as shown above are modified in the following way:

```
$ cat file.txt | sed -r $EXPR
    disutil_screening = 0.00000; # favorable
    disutil_screening = 0.00009; # base
#   disutil_screening = 0.00019; # unfavorable
```

Once I know how to do this (replace the leading "#" with "" for the "favorable" line), then I believe I can figure out how to add a "#" to the "base" line (i.e. comment out lines that are currently not commented-out).

**Note**: I'm open to using awk for this task instead of sed, but I'm a little intimidated by awk, never having used it before.

Comment: FYI: Actually, there are many different `disutil_*` statements in the text file.  But for the purpose of this question, I simply assumed that the only one is `disutil_screening`.  There are actually `disutil_biopsy`, `disutil_surgery`, etc.  Because there are many disutil's, I need to make this toggling of commented lines automated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that what you need is called grouping. Try this one:

```
$ cat file.txt | sed -r 's/#([\t]disutil_screening[\ =0-9\.;]+# favorable)/\1/'
```

I wrapped all the match expect the first commenting character into the group and then replace the whole match with this group so the first character is removed.

Comment: Ahh, so for the case of commenting out a currently uncommented line, I could do something like this, right?  `'s/^([\t]disutil_screening[\ =0-9\.;]+# favorable)/#\1/'`

Comment: How come when I use your sed expression but add the `-i` option, I get the error: `invalid reference \1 on \`s' command's RHS`?

Comment: If you're using -r you don't need to escape the brackets. I suspect you're escaping the brackets, so \1 is looking for a group that doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm not escaping the brackets.  Here is the command I'm using: `sed -ir 's/#([\t]disutil_screening[\ =0-9\.;]+# unfavorable)/\1/' file.txt`

Comment: @synaptik "Ahh, so for the case of commenting out" - yes, exactly.

Comment: @hoipolloi Please see my reply to your comment about escaping the brackets. (I forgot to `@` address you in that reply.)

Comment: @hoipolloi nevermind, I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825618/sed-works-but-sed-i-returns-an-error)

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I came up with. Note, -i makes the replacement inline (i.e. your original file will be changed).

```
$ sed -i 's/^#\(.*# favorable\)$/ \1/' text.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm glad to see your answer which supplements AlexAtNet's by demonstrating the syntax for capture groups when not using the `-r` option.  I learn more from seeing both ways :)

Answer (score 3):

using awk

```
awk -F= '$2 ~ / favorable/{sub("#","")}1' temp.txt
```

Output

```
   disutil_screening = 0.00000; # favorable
    disutil_screening = 0.00009; # base
#   disutil_screening = 0.00019; # unfavorable
```