# Sed command - order of option flags matters? (-ir vs -ri)

Tags: regex, sed

Imagine the following data stored in file `data.txt`

```
1, StringString, AnotherString 545
```

I want to replace "StringString" with "Strung" with the following code

```bash
sed -ir 's/String+/Strung/g' data.txt
```

But it won't work. This works though:

```bash
sed -ri 's/String+/Strung/g' data.txt
```

I don't see any reason why the order of option flags would matter. Is it a bug or is there an explanation?

---

Please note that I'm not looking for a workaround but rather why the order of `-ir` and `-ri` matters.

*Sidenotes:  The switch `-i` "edits the file in place" while `-r` allows "extended regular expression" (allowing the `+` operator). I'm running sed 4.2.1 Dec. 2010 on Ubuntu 12.10.*

Comment: Sidenote: `String+` means `Strin(g)+`. If you want to match one or more occurrences of "String", use `(String)+`, but that replaces "AnotherString" with "AnotherStrung", which I don't think is what you want. So, if you want to match exactly two occurrences, use `(String){2}`, or if you want to match two or more, use `(String){2,}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When doing `-ir` you are specifying that "r" should be the suffix for the backup file.

You should be able to do `-i -r` if you need them in that order

Answer (score 7):

Did you check `sed --help` or `man sed`?

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
     edit files in place (makes backup if extension supplied).
     The default operation mode is to break symbolic and hard links.
     This can be changed with --follow-symlinks and --copy.
```

Comment: Doing!! Oh, I just found the file called "data.txtr" in the directory - which was created as a backup.  I was expecting a space to seperate the suffix but now it makes sense.