# Sed command works with pipe but gives error when the input is a file

Tags: bash, sed

I made a sed command

```
$ echo 'HttpContext.Current.Session["mode"] = mode;' | 
sed -r "s/Current.Session\[([^]]*)\](\s*)=([^;]*)/Session\.SetString(\1,\3)/g"

output: HttpContext.Session.SetString("mode", mode);
```

and it works just as i want it to.
The problem comes when I try to do the same thing to a file:

```
$ echo 'HttpContext.Current.Session["mode"] = mode;' > test.txt
$ sed -ir "s/Current.Session\[([^]]*)\](\s*)=([^;]*)/Session\.SetString(\1,\3)/g" test.txt
```

I get an error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 69: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS`
```

I don't really get why it works with a simple pipe but not for changing a file.

Comment: Replace `sed -ir` with `sed -E -i ''` or `sed -ri`

Comment: @anubhava Why? Isn't that equivalent except that it also makes a backup?

Comment: @wjandrea: There are non-gnu versions of `sed` that require a file extension name after `-i` option.

Comment: `sed -E -i` seems to actually work. Same with `sed -Ei` for some reason. I guess order is the problem.

Comment: With GNU `sed`, because `-i` takes an *optional* argument, `sed -ir` seems to treat `r` as the suffix name, not the `-r` option required to interpret the script as intended. When you change the order, although it's conceivable that your script could be the suffix, `sed` is smart enough to notice that if it treats the script as the argument to `-i`, there is no argument left to use as the script.

Comment: The `-i` option is, IMO, a bit of an antipattern in the first place. If you want to edit a file, not a stream, consider using `ed` instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sed command - order of option flags matters? (-ir vs -ri)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525378/sed-command-order-of-option-flags-matters-ir-vs-ri) (This is for GNU sed. If you're using a different version and can't figure out how the solution would work, LMK.)

Comment: @chepner : Basically correct, but not smartness, but simply defined behaviour: In the Gnu sed man page, the option is described as `-i[SUFFIX]`. This means that `-iE` must be understood as using `E` as backup suffix, and - due to the square brackets in the docs - it means that both  `-i -E` and `-Ei` would use the default suffix, plus turn on extended regexps.

Comment: @user1934428 Right; I'm referring to a situation like `sed -i 's/.../.../' foo.txt`, where interpreting `s/.../.../` as an optional argument to `-i` doesn't leave enough arguments for both the script and the file to apply the script to.